# How to access html5 audio play() event in codebehind asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, audio

I have an html5 audio tag in repeater. When user clicks button I want to fire play() event in codebehind. I can find audio and give src but can't fire play(). 
Ps:Autoplay is working only one time for another audio not working.
My codes are:

**aspx in repeater**

```
<audio id="player2" runat="server" src="" type="audio/mp3" 
controls="controls" preload="none" autoplay="autoplay">
```

**Codebehind**

```
        HtmlAudio audio = (HtmlAudio)e.Item.FindControl("player2");
         switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "play":

                audio.Src = dt.Rows[0]["AudioPath"].ToString();                    
                **audio play() ?**                   
                break;             

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naturally for another audio it will not work. It will work only for the first one. Because you gave the same ID to all of them. ID also should be dynamic, depending on your audio. For example, you may load it from database: *<%#Eval("id")%>*.
You have some control, when clicking on that control audio have to be played. Would be better if you will do it on a link. For example,

```
<a href="javascript:PlayAudio(<%#Eval("id") %>)">
     <img src="...." width=".." height=".." />
</a>
```

And then write javascript function:

```
PlayAudio(id){
   document.getElementById('audio'+id).setAttribute("autoplay", "autoplay");
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hello @Khazratbek thanks for reply. But I can't give <audio> dynamic ID because it's runat="server". That's my another question with full code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921848/html5-audio-autoplay-in-asp-net
Can you check and give me advice? Thanks..

Comment: @Khazratbek Teamviewer sessions are not encouraged as such sessions are of no value to future visitors.
If you want to start a discussion use chat. Note that this is being discussed on meta, see [Should we allow people to offer to help through outside communications like Team Viewer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311869)

Comment: @DavidPostill they create a question because of me =) =) =) Really funny. I just tried to help a user, as he tried himself and couldn't generate the code what he need. Next time I just will use chat for that and then upload final code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

in ASPX page:

```
 <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_sound" Visible="false"/>
```

In code behind:

```
//clear label on load page , and set value in your event
public void goSound()
{
  lbl_sound.Text="<div><audio autoplay hidden><source src='Sound/myaudio.wav' type='audio/mpeg'></audio></div>"
}
```

it worked for me